# Test enum for equality in for ... where clause

Tags: swift, for-loop, enums

How can I test for enum equality when a `case` has an associated value? A contrived example:

```
enum Status : Equatable {
    case success
    case failed(error: String)

    static func == (lhs: Status, rhs: Status) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.success, .success), (.failed, .failed):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

let statuses = [
    Status.success,
    .failed(error: "error 1"),
    .failed(error: "error 2"),
    .success
]

// Failed: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Status' and '_'
for s in statuses where s == .failed {
    print(s)
}
```

(I know I can test for `s != .success` but the actual enum has more cases so they are a hassle)

Comment: Because you consider any `failed` to be equal to another (which is weird; usually they'd be the same if the `error` was the same), you can do `for s in statuses where s == .failed(error: "") { ... }`. Note, with `if`, you can do `if case`, e.g. `if case .failed = someStatus { ... }`.

Comment: If you don't mind extracting the associated value in the process, you can do `for case .failed(let str) in statuses { print("failure: \(str)") }`.

Comment: This is somewhat in jest, but it does work: `for case (.failed, let s) in zip(statuses, statuses) { print(s) }`.

Comment: Just for fun: `for s in statuses where { if case .failed = $0 { return true } else { return false }}(s) { ...} ` :)

Comment: Many good comments here (why don't you guys add an answer?). I think @Rob has it closest to what I want. I will accept that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `if case`:

```
for status in statuses {
    if case .failed = status {
        ...
    }
}
```

But, unfortunately, you can't use `case` with the `where` clause of `for` loop.

---

In this case, though, because you've defined `.failed` to be equal to another regardless of what the `error` associated value was, you theoretically could do:

```
for status in statuses where status == .failed(error: "") {
    show("\(status)")
}
```

I'm not crazy about that pattern because (a) it's contingent upon the fact that `.failed` values are equal even if they have different `error` associated values; and (b) it results in code that is easily misunderstood.